# Best practice for polymorphism in interelated C++ classes?

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have a couple of interrelated classes that will be used by multiple different algorithms

Example:

```
struct B;

struct A {
    B* parent;
};

struct B {
    std::vector<A*> children;
};
```

Each algorithm may want to specialize these classes based on what they are doing with them, so presumably we they should derive from A and B

```
struct Aderived : A {...};
struct Bderived : B {...};
```

but methods in `Aderived` will want to treat `parent` as `Bderived*` (to access methods or members added by `Bderived`) and `Bderived` will want to treat the elements of `children` as `Aderived*`.

1) Is there a good way for methods in `Aderived` and `Bderived` to avoid having to do static casts on `parent` and `children` every time they want to access a method of `Bderived` and `Aderived`, respectively.

2) How would you even get something like this to compile anyways since you can't forward declare that a class is derived from another...

```
struct Aderived : public A {
    int a;
    void x() { static_cast<Bderived*>(b)->b = 1; }   // ERROR
};

struct Bderived : public B {
    int b;
    void x() { static_cast<Aderived*>(avec.back())->a = 1; }
};
```

Comment: Which is the purpose of base classes `A` and `B`?

Comment: I really don't understand why you can't just have the members be defined in the baseclasses as types `Bderived* parent` and `std::vector<Aderived*> children`, since you always want to treat them as such? I really believe you're overengineering this and making it more complicated than it has to be.

Comment: @ruohola probably

Answer (score 1):

define A and B as templates:

```
template < class T1 >
struct A
{
    T1* parent;
};

template < class T2 >
struct B 
{
    std::vector < T2* > children;
};
```

and while inheritance go for:

```
struct Aderived : public A < Bderived >
{
  // ...
};

struct Bderived : public B < Aderived >
{
  //...
};
```

Comment: @JerryJeremiah: you have lot of typos, but once fixed, [it compiles](https://www.godbolt.org/z/Ez-1pX)

Comment: @Jarod42  Thanks for that.  I knew I was doing something wrong.

Comment: Thought about CRTP but then you don't have an actual base class anymore, i.e.,  if ```A``` and ```B``` are supposed to be common data structures that are passed to other algorithms then this doesn't help

Answer (score 0):

Just declare the member functions of `A` that cast `B*` to `Bderived*` and define them after defining `Bderived`:

```cpp
struct Aderived : public A {
    int a;
    void x();
};

struct Bderived : public B {
    int b;
    void x() { static_cast<Aderived*>(avec.back())->a = 1; }
};

inline void Aderived::x() { static_cast<Bderived*>(b)->b = 1; }
```